# Selenium C# не работает

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

При запуске программа сразу закрывается и VS выводит такую ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код программы:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

namespace WebDriver
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://google.com");
            driver.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Все необходимые элементы добавил. Selenium у меня последней версии ( 3.0.0 ).

Comment: Она же явно жалуется на отсутствие драйвера для Хрома. У вас браузер корпорации добра установлен?

Comment: @Bulson Да, установлен. С мозилой пробовал тоже (она у меня установлена), но ошибка такая же появляется.

Comment: @Bulson, разве помимо Chrome не нужен еще и chromedriver.exe?

Comment: @Bulson он у меня есть.

Answer (score 3):

Ваша ошибка в том, что вы не передаете в `ChromeDriver()` путь до `chromedriver.exe`, если вы не хотите передавать в него путь, тогда `chromedriver.exe` должен лежать в папке `bin\Debug` либо `bin\Release`

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver("путь до папки с chromedriver.exe");
```

**Небольшая инструкция и пример:**

1. Скачиваем [Selenium WebDriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) для C#
2. Распаковываем куда-нибудь, например, `D:\WebDriver`
3. Скачиваем последнюю версию [ChromeDriver](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.25/)
4. Кладем скачанный ChromeDriver в созданную папку на шаге 2, в моем случае `D:\WebDriver`
5. Создаем или открываем проект в студии
6. В референсы проекта добавляем 4 DLL из папки `D:\WebDriver`

Дальше пишем код:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string chromeDriverDir = @"D:\WebDriver"; // в этой папке должен лежать chromedriver.exe

        using (IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverDir)) // передаем путь до chromedriver.exe
        { 
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://google.com/");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("lst-ib")).SendKeys("StackOverFlow");
            driver.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать IE вместо хрома(Добавьте [IEDriverServer.exe](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5PvMQh4hyz0U2xYVGNCUXJYb3M/view?usp=sharing)) или сами найдите если стесняетесь качать exe файл:) должен лежать в директории с исполняймым файлом. У меня работает с phantomjs.exe браузером, но вы наверное можете использовать любой другой аналог.

```
using SeleniumWebDriverHelper; using System;


static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var browser = SeleniumHelper.GetBrowser(SeleniumHelper.BrowserType.InternetExplorer, true);
        browser.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.ru");
    }
}
```

Пример можете скачать [тут](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5PvMQh4hyz0dXhoRE9Ua1dZSFU/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: А как его добавлять?

Comment: Добавить существующий элемент в проект выбрать этот .ехе файл,

Comment: У меня все равно такая ошибка выходит. Где нужно выбрать этот .exe файл?

Comment: В ответ  я добавил пример там есть все dll  и exe!

Comment: Я сделал все как у вас, но у меня почему-то до сих пор такая же ошибка выходит.

Comment: Если речь о WebDriver, то не нужно IE. Firefox понимает этот протокол без драйвера.

Comment: Скиньте еще раз текст и скрин ошибки. после того как вы запускаете пример который я выложил, как странно что у вас такая же ошибка, так как вы не запускаете хром