# Selenium C# переехать на Windows

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Здравствуйте!У меня стоит Linux. В Monodevelop сделал проект используя Selenium (C#/chromedriver). У меня все работает, решил проверить эту программу на Windows. Собрал пакет, запустил на Windows - программа вылетела. Ошибка была такая:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**У меня два вопроса:**

1) Как это исправить?

2) И как сделать билд для Windows?

**Вот пример кода:**

```
IWebDriver driver = null;
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions ();
if (proxyEnable) {
    var proxy = new Proxy ();
    proxy.HttpProxy = proxyList [random.Next (0, numOfProxies)];
    chromeOptions.Proxy = proxy;
}

if (numOfUserAgents > 0)
    chromeOptions.AddArgument ("--user-agent=" + userAgentList [random.Next (0, numOfUserAgents)]);

driver = new ChromeDriver (path, chromeOptions);
```

Comment: "Ошибка была примерно такая: OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome... нет необходимых элементов. " - ну и ответ на вопрос "как это исправить?" тогда будет очевиден - добавить необходимые элементы... Убедительная просьба более точно описать ошибку.

Comment: @BlackWitcher спасибо за критику, добавил скриншот.

Comment: Вот теперь могу предположить, что у вас на винде просто не та версия WebDriver.dll, которая ему нужна. Например, в ней 'MainClass' как-то иначе реализует методы `Surf()` и `Main()`.

Comment: @BlackWitcher "Surf()" - метод, который я создал сам. Что мне нужно сделать? Скачать другой WebDriver.dll ?

Comment: Возможно да, но вот какой именно - не могу сказать точно, ибо смотрите, изначально он ругается на тип `OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions`, вероятно, причина именно в нем, а методы `Surf()` и `Main()` - это методы, где этот тип как-то задействуется. Может быть есть где-то в самом Selenium указание на нужную версию WebDriver?

Comment: посмотрите тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/587640/selenium-c-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82/587794#587794

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/588858/192029

Comment: @tCode не помогло.

Comment: @Reaget вы при инициализации Chromedriver передаете в него ChromeOptions? Без кода сложно сказать в чем проблема...

Comment: @tCode сейчас часть кода покажу.

Comment: @Reaget, уберите из инициализции ChromeDriver из параметров chromeOptions и оставьте только path и попробуйте

Comment: @tCode вышла такая же ошибка

Comment: @Reaget, значит действительно ошибка в WebDriver.dll, скачайте новую библиотку и обновите ее в проекте, и обязательно скачайте последнюю версию хромдрайвера

Comment: @tCode Если вам не сложно, можете дать на них ссылки, пожалуйста?

Comment: @Reaget, здесь вот я указал все ссылки ru.stackoverflow.com/a/588858/192029

Comment: @tCode Почему ваш пример работает на "Ура!", а мой не в какую не хочет? Если я скину вам исходный код, вы сможете его проверить?

Comment: @tCode я скачал все самое последнее, не помогло.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48301/discussion-between-tcode-and-reaget).

Comment: @tCode Давайте.