# Сохранение изображений из гугл картинок C#

Tags: c#, парсер, webbrowser, google-images

Имеется в компоненте webbrowser загруженная страница с определенными картинками из гугл картинок. Как можно сохранить выбранное мной изображение, если я, допустим, открыл его для просмотра (кликнув по нему)?
Думал сделать так:
после нажатия на изображение, если оно удовлетворяет требованиям, нажать кнопку "в полном размере" и тут же как-то перехватить ссылку на это изображение, а затем сохранить на диск. Но понятия не имею как это делать. Может кто подсказать способ решения этой проблемы?

Answer (score 1):

Именно на C#, как вариант, вы можете использовать фантомбраузер, переходить по нужной ссылки в гугл картинках , получать страницу с нужными картинками и парсить  используя косвенные признаки для выбора нужной картинки. Я выкладывал пример в этом [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/587640/selenium-c-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82/587794#587794)

Comment: А что такое "фантомбраузер"?

Comment: @Bulson отредактировал ответ, дал ссылку на пример

Comment: @YuryBakharev, а в чем его отличие от WebDriver, подскажи плиз?

Comment: @tCode на сколько я знаю, фантомбраузер парсит страницу в свою внутреннюю модель и предоставляет доступ к элементам, параллельно все запросы транслируются в реальный браузер, и для использования конкретного нужно использовать свой webdriver

Comment: @YuryBakharev, понял, спс

Comment: А помимо этого есть какой-нибудь способ? Я пробовал получать html страницы и с помощью html agillity pack парсить, но там ведь почти все картинки в js, фиг что сделаешь

Comment: @АндрейФедоров готового решения, как парсить ответы от гугла, на сколько я знаю, нет(не считая официального апи). К каждой задаче нужно подходить индивидуально, попробуйте конкретизировать, что именно вы хотите и возможно вам помогут!

Comment: мне нужно каким-нибудь образом получать src выбранных мной изображений (выбираю просто кликнув по нему). Но как их получить из кода -  я не знаю, т.к. там ведь все через Js идет.

Comment: @АндрейФедоров ну а критерий отбора изображений какой? И когда вы используете фантомбраузер там не все в JS, а именно можно получить src картинки.